# How to use WSDL url to create a request for data

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

I have a WSDL url(http:localhost:8080/userdata?wsdl) and I want to create a request to this webservice so I can fetch the data for further processing. Can I do this without `wsimport`?

If I have to create package from `wsimport`, how I can create a client which will use generated classes to create the XML request?

If I can do this without `wsimport` , how I can create a client which will create the XML request?

New to webservices, links to documentation would be appreciated. I am trying to understand this at the moment http://java.dzone.com/news/5-techniques-create-web-servic

Comment: Do you want to create a Java WS Client and a Java WS Implementation of the WSDL? Or do you already have a working WS Implementation, and you want to invoke it to test it?

Comment: I want to create a WS client.

Comment: That tutorial you linked to is very old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CXF wsdl2Java to generate a client code for the web service.

Once you run the wsdl2java , you will get a set of java classes generated for you. You can then use those classes to call the services without any explicit conversion of XML - the underlying framework will do it for you automatically. You can start with http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html

I proposed CXF while you can look for many other alternatives - However, i have found CXF to be very feature rich and will help you in developing/working with web services.

Comment: A beginers tip: HelloService is the name of the service class and depends on wsdl. You will have to search for the file name ending with Service and use the correct interface.

Comment: I have tried to use wsimport to generate java classes, but what if the webservice is updated, I will have to generate the classes again. There should be a dynamic way to just use wsdl URL.

Comment: The failure is not by chance - it is by design. WSDL is a contract and all clients must adhere to it.However, nobody can stop you from sending XML(created from string concatenations) over HTTP and hitting the service. However, here also, if the service (and hence wsdl) is updated, the request will fail. There exists many hacks but each will force you to use a thick Proxy framework. In case you are looking for flexible way of creating services, look for wsdl less REST paradigm - it is better than creating an contract and then updating(breaking) at will.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what Akhilesh said you can also create a Dynamic client for invoking WSDL. I have done it recently and i found it a little bit better then using CXF as dynamic client does not generate any code whatsoever. You just pass in the parameters to it and it does all the job for you. You can find a "shell" to build your own client [HERE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxwsdynclient.html)